# live http streaming in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android Which involves searching nearby locations and globally. I am facing a problem when i try to do live http streaming in android stimulator.What to do with live streaming....Anybody knows can respond how should i proceed....
I have tried the code like url 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321682/android-source-code-streaming-media

http://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/source/browse/trunk/android/streaming_audio/#streaming_audio%2Fres%2Fdrawable

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Comment: State the "a problem" you are facing.

Comment: Problem is that video is not being played in emulator.When i run application......What should i do?/ now

Answer (score 0):

Hey Tushar use an actual device instead of emulator..Emulator do not run all the videos

Answer (score 0):

Yes watching live streams doesn't work with emulators. better test it on devices with OS at least greater than 3.0. Below that guarantee cant be given as I have observed. And I use standard code using VideoView for live streams. They play but don't run as smoothly as on TV / Web. If you have any ideas, please share with me.
Using Vitamio Plugin had good effects but our company isn't allowing third party interfere so...